# How to run multiple Graph Engine instances on the same machine?

Tags: graphengine

I want to run multiple Graph Engine instances on the same machine by listening on different ports.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide some more information regarding the question so that it will be easier to understand for other users . You can check [How to ask a complete question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look here: https://www.graphengine.io/docs/manual/Config/config-v2.html#server

When defining multiple servers on the same machine, you can put the assemblies into different folders. In the config file, you can then identify each of them with a combination of address and assembly path.

There are two binding rules for an instance:

1. The Endpoint property matches one of the network interfaces of the machine on which the Graph Engine instance is running.
2. If AssemblyPath is specified, it matches the directory where the running Graph Engine instance resides.

Also please check the version of your GraphEngine.Core package. Only the latest package supports the new configuration file format.